# React django file upload difference in content-length

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, file-upload, axios, upload

I'm trying to upload a PDF file from my react client to my django server (both running locally on my laptop), but I'm observing a difference in the size of the file that is sent from my react client and the file received in the request receieved at my server. The file received in the request at the server does not seem to be a valid PDF file either. This seems to be happening for other file types as well.

Attaching relevant screenshots and snippets below where I'm trying to upload a PDF file which is ~4.5 MB in size:

React client snippet for uploading the file:

```js
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', acceptedFiles[0]);  // acceptedFiles comes from a form input

    const uploadFilesResponse = await axios.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `/api/documents/upload/${pathToUpload}`,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    });
```

The network tab indicating the request I've sent and the file in the request payload:

[image]
[image]

Here's the corresponding request received at the server

[image]

Even the on disk temporary file created by django for the upload highlighted above (`/var/folders/tf/7xrq4m4j11dcfkngpz9j3rfm0000gn/T/tmpil4f5hsn.upload.pdf`) seems to be an invalid file which is ~8.5 MB in size.

The request object shared above is the request object received at my views before I do any processing.

Can someone help me figuring out why this is happening and how I can go about resolving this?

PS: In case it helps, the configuration I'm using:

python packages

```
django>=4.1.4
djangorestframework>=3.14.0
```

`INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE` in my `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```